# react-search: The type definition `index.d.ts` does not exist. Create one and try again

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, sharepoint-framework, pnp

I am new to SharePoint and I'm trying to deploy a modern Search Web Part following the instructions here [sp-dev-fx-webparts/samples/react-search/](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-search)

When I run `tsd install` on the command prompt, it returns this error message.

> The type definition `index.d.ts` does not exist. Create one and try again.

What do I do?

#spfx  #spfx-webparts

Answer (score 0):

Tsd versions above 0.6.5 don't work the same way at all any more.

I found this on an unrelated project with a line that installed tsd globally like this: `npm install -g tsd` which picked up 0.7.x, a relatively new version of the tsd package, with so many breaking changes I'm convinced it's not supposed to work like it used to.

It will be a problem with the `sp-build-web` package so I don't know if you can edit what tsd version it tries to install.